# Change java compiler version in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How to change java compiler versions to 1.8 in eclipse java oxygen?
I have to write something for this version of the compiler.
How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To change the compiler version in eclipse you need to go to **Windows > Preferences > Java > Compiler**. There you will see **Compiler Compilation Level** where in drop-down you will see all compiler version available in system. You can select desired compiler version here for all projects available in workspace (as in below image).

[image]

Along that you can enable project specific compiler setting by **Right Click On Project >  Properties > Java Compiler**. There you will find Compiler Compilation Level and change the compiler for project (as in below Image).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to add java 8 in Eclipse build path. To do that, in Eclipse, go to Preferences > Java > Installed JREs then, Select existing jre or jdk and click on edit. A new window will pop up with JRE home assign jdk path by clicking on Directory(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221). Click finish, then Apply and Close. You should be good to go.